# How do I remove a tag from a photo in Facebook?

Tags: facebook

I was going through a friend's tagged pictures and accidentally tagged another of our mutual friends in it. How do I remove the tag? (The picture was uploaded by someone who isn't a friend.)

Answer (score 1):

There's no option to remove a tag of your friend you requested on others photo but however you can remove your own tag.

If you tag yourself or your friend in somebody else's album, they are sent a request to accept the tag and its on them to accept or the reject the tag.

And if you want the tag to be removed, try to message the person who uploaded the photo and ask him to remove the tag. That's all you can do on your side.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to the other answers you can remove the request. Hover over the name of the person you sent the tag request for and it will come up with a small version of their wall. At the very top of this it says 'remove request', simply click it and you're done!

Comment: P.S. This works even if this is not your own photo

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the official answer](https://www.facebook.com/help/196434507090362) - adding it here for the sake of google searchers like me! The only issue is, the tag still shows in the post "edited" link.

> Even well-meaning friends sometimes tag you in unflattering photos or
> mention you in stories you’d rather not share. If you’re not happy
> with a post you’re tagged in, you can remove the tag or ask the person
> who tagged you to take the photo or post down: Go to the post or
> photo. Click  in the top right. Click Remove tag. Choose to remove the
> tag or ask the person who shared the photo to take it down

Answer (score -1):

On the side of the photo it will have the people who are tagged, hover over it and it'll give you a small picture of the friend you accidentally tagged, in that little picture it'll have the option "remove request" click in that and you're done.

Comment: Not true. This is only if you own the photo, not if it is a friends photo.

Comment: Worse yet: even if you own the photo, sometimes it won't let you remove the tag.

Answer (score -1):

1. Click on the photo in question.  See on the right side who posted that photo.  There is an option "Allowed on Timeline"
2. Select the option "Hidden From Timeline"
3. Click on Remove Tag option
4. Click on "I want to untag myself" option
5. Click on "Remove tag"
6. Click on Okay

Answer (score -1):

The picture you are getting accidentally tagged or requested to tag yourself. You have to open the same picture on laptop, cause on Android mobile we can not have an option available or might be its getting lost. However on laptop you have to click on the same picture. On the right hand side you will see your name. Don't click on your name as it will turn into your Facebook profile page. Click on the side arrow and there you got it option for removing your tag is available.